# AMPScript LookUp not retrieving any value

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, lookup

I've added a Lookup in my email to retrieve the language of the customer but, despite there is data, the function doesn't retrieve anything (I tried with different values or Data Extensions but with the same result).

```
%%[ 
VAR @SubKey, @EmailAddress, @language

SET @EmailAddress = emailaddr 
SET @SubKey = _subscriberkey
SET @language = Lookup("Account_Salesforce","Language__pc","PersonContactId",@skey)
]%%
```

I tried performing a real email sent instead of the test and preview but no success either.

Comment: Tried adding the `ent.` prefix: `"ent.Account_Salesforce"`?

Comment: I tried it too but nothing. There is only one Business Unit in the account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it. You have set a @SubKey, while in the function you used @skey. Try this:

```
%%[ 
VAR @SubKey, @EmailAddress, @language

SET @EmailAddress = emailaddr 
SET @SubKey = _subscriberkey
SET @language = Lookup("Account_Salesforce","Language__pc","PersonContactId",@SubKey)
]%%
```

Comment: you are right, it works. what an error (facepalm)

Comment: no worries, happens to the best :-)

Comment: One of the best helps offered here :)